# Does the ListView redraw the underlaying model if the model changes?

Tags: qt, listview, qml, qt5, qabstractlistmodel

The question is basically the title, but some more detail:

I have subclassed the `QAbstractListModel`, lets name it `myModel`.
I am creating the content of `myModel` in c++ code, then feeding it into a `ListView` in QML. 
My code modifies `myModel` in C++ code and I can see the modifications right away in my `ListView`, which is fine.
My question is, that does the `ListView` redraws all of its elements, when the underlaying model changes (like adding an item) or just draws the new item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the `ListView` delegate I have checked how many times does `Component.onCompleted` and `Component.onDestruction` called. The results are, that when a new item is inserted the `Component.onCompleted` is called only once and when an item is removed the `Component.onDestruction` is called only once, which means that `ListView` doesn't redraw the whole list when inserting and removing items!

Answer (score 1):

That depends upon what signals you model emits, some of which may not be obvious if you just override some protected methods. See the documentation of the signals in the QAbstractItemModel Class.